# How to call a method of an object from a function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have decided to integrate an animation object(`FX`) in my application for drop-down actions of two clickable elements and I later wrote a reusable function to trigger the drop-down action for the respective elements.
However I can not seem to call the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods of the animation object into my reusable `dropdownFunction`.
How would I successfully call the object methods from my `dropdownFunction`?

Navigation bar(`html.erb`)

```
 <header>
   <div class="dropdown">
     <div onclick="dropdownFunction('current-user');" class="button-sign-out">
       <%= gravatar_for current_user %>
     </div>
      <div id="current-user" class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><%= link_to "#{current_user.name.truncate(13)}", user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1><%= link_to "threadly", views_path %></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= link_to new_view_path do %>
       <div class="button-terrance">
          terrance
      </div>
      <% end %>
     <%= link_to users_path do %>
       <div class="button-discover tool-tip-up">
          <i class="fa fa-compass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span class="tool-tip-text">Discover</span>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <div class="dropdown-container" data-behavior="notifications" data-notifications='<%= render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json] %>'> <!-- wrapper -->
      <div onclick="dropdownFunction('notification');" class="button-notification" data-behavior="notifications-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
         <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <div class="count" data-behavior="unread-count"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="notification-bell dropdown-content-notification-items" id="notification" data-behavior="notification-items">
        <!-- Notifications -->
      </div>
    </div>
      <%= form_tag(users_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autocomplete: :off, 
            class: "user-search", spellcheck: false, placeholder: "Search" %>
      <% end %>
   </header>
```

The integrated animation class(`.js`)

```
// Animations FX Class
(function() {
  var FX = {
    easing: {
      linear: function(progress) {
        return progress;
      },
      quadratic: function(progress) {
        return Math.pow(progress, 2);
      },
      swing: function(progress) {
        return 0.5 - Math.cos(progress * Math.PI) / 2;
      },
      circ: function(progress) {
        return 1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(progress));
      },
      back: function(progress, x) {
        return Math.pow(progress, 2) * ((x + 1) * progress - x);
      },
      bounce: function(progress) {
        for (var a = 0, b = 1, result; 1; a += b, b /= 2) {
          if (progress >= (7 - 4 * a) / 11) {
            return -Math.pow((11 - 6 * a - 11 * progress) / 4, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
          }
        }
      },
      elastic: function(progress, x) {
        return Math.pow(2, 10 * (progress - 1)) * Math.cos(20 * Math.PI * x / 3 * progress);
      }
    },
    animate: function(options) {
      var start = new Date();
      var id = setInterval(function() {
        var timePassed = new Date() - start;
        var progress = timePassed / options.duration;
        if (progress > 1) {
          progress = 1;
        }
        options.progress = progress;
        var delta = options.delta(progress);
        options.step(delta);
        if (progress === 1) {
          clearInterval(id);
          options.complete;
        }
      }, options.delay || 10);
    },
    fadeOut: function(element, options) {
      var to = 1;
      var target = document.getElementById(element);
      this.animate({
        duration: options.duration,
        delta: function(progress) {
          progress = this.progress;
          return FX.easing.swing(progress);
        },
        complete: options.complete,
        step: function(delta) {
          target.style.opacity = to - delta;
        }
      });
    },
    fadeIn: function(element, options) {
      var to = 0;
      var target = document.getElementById(element);
      this.animate({
        duration: options.duration,
        delta: function(progress) {
          progress = this.progress;
          return FX.easing.swing(progress);
        },
        complete: options.complete,
        step: function(delta) {
          target.style.opacity = to + delta;
        }
      });
    }
  };
  window.FX = FX;
})();
```

Reusable dropdown fuction(`.js`)

```
var dropdownElements = ["notification", "current-user"];

// OnClick event toggles between hiding and showing the dropdown content
function dropdownFunction(element) {
    for (var dropdownElement in dropdownElements) {
        if (dropdownElements[dropdownElement] !== element) {
            document.getElementById(dropdownElements[dropdownElement]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    // My attempt at calling the methods
    document.getElementById(element).style.display === "block" ? FX.fadeOut(element) : FX.fadeIn(element);

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = ev => {
        if (!ev.target.matches(element)) {
            document.getElementById(element).style.display = "none";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: have you tried `window.FX.fadeOut()` at the bottom of the `FX` class its got `window.FX = FX;`

Comment: Yes, just tried it now. Still no avail.

Comment: Thats not a class. Thats just an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) containing functions that you assign to a global. I would really advise against reinventing the wheel and creating a javascript based animation library in 2017. Using CSS based animations is way better from a performance standpoint as they leverage the GPU.

Comment: What do you see in the console? Is FX defined when you go to call it's methods?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that even provide javascript animations as a fallback for browsers that don't support CSS based animations. But in 2017 thats really a non issue - if a client does not support CSS based animations its a really old crappy browser and is probally better off without the bells and whistles.

Comment: The performance issue is very real with handheld devices. Doing javascript based animations is really ineffective since you're basically just making the processor figure out every 1px nudge in between states. CSS based animations are deterministic. You declare the steps and the browser can figure out how to animate it using the GPU which is really good at it.

Comment: As to why `window.FX` may not be available - it depends on the order your javascript is included. If you are using Spockets and `//= require_tree .` the files are included in the manifest in alphabetical order.  Explicitly requiring is better if your code relies on a specific ordering. Please add the <head> section of your `layout.html.erb` and the `application.js` or whatever file you are linking to.

Comment: @max This is true, I have an idea of what you are talking about. I think it is the rendering order that is also making the procedure ineffective. Ok so how would I use css in this case if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations